# Linq Filter Array of Delimited Strings

Tags: c#, arrays, linq, linq-to-objects

I have a string like this:

> > RoleId,RoleName|CategoryId,CategoryName

I split them first like this:

```
string delm = "RoleId,RoleName|CategoryId,CategoryName";

string[] FieldsToReplace = attributes[0].IdsToReplaceWith.Split('|');
```

Suppose i have  a variable in which i have RoleId:

```
string test = "RoleId";
```

Now what i am trying to get each the array item in which has string **RoleId**, i don't want to use contains i need exact match.

I have tried this query:

```
        var test = FieldsToReplace
                   .Where(x=>FieldsToReplace
                   .All(y => y.Split(',').Equals(delm))).ToArray();
```

i can harcode like this for first index:

```
var IdProperty = FieldsToReplace.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Split(',')[0] == delm);
```

but i want it dynamic so it check each item of array which i got after `,` split.

but it returns no record.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: y.Split(',') returns an array. Maybe you need y.Split(',')[1] ?

Comment: I'm not sure I follow.. What's the expected output?

Comment: output is to reutrn that array item which has Roleid exact matched, actually i need to split every item of array on ``,`` and then check if matches with RoleId, if matches return that item of array

Comment: why i am getting downvotes my question is genuine and i am not able to solve my issue

Comment: When you say return that item of the array, you're not making sense. The array you're searching through, if split again on a `,`, when matched simply returns the string you're matching.

Comment: There's not much point returning the thing you're looking for. Do you mean you want the index number for the item?

Comment: @Enigmativity every item has delimeted string and i want to split on '','' and check if it matches my required string if matches return the main array item in which it is matching in RoleId case index 0 of arrray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to split on your elements of the array. Besides that it seems appropriate to check if any element of these splitted ones are equal to your comparison string:

```
var test =
    FieldsToReplace
        .Where(x => x.Split(',')
            .Any(y => y.Equals(prop.Name)))
        .ToArray();
```

Comment: i was in doubt that i need to use Any but i was not getting where to put..Thanks by the way